# How to store results of PDO/SQL Count in ModX Revo?

Tags: php, sql, pdo, modx, modx-revolution

I need to store the results from an SQL COUNT query in a PHP variable.

I know ModX uses PDO to run its SQL queries but I am unsure of how to go about creating this.

So far I have tried:

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT (*) FROM `table` WHERE x = $x";
$results = $modx->query($sql);
$count = mysql_fetch_array($results);
echo $count;
```

and:

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT (*) FROM `table` WHERE x = $x";
$results = $modx->getCount($sql);
echo $results;
```

but with no results.

Would anyone know the correct way to do this in ModX (Revo) and PDO?

Comment: How about you start by [reading the *fine* manual](http://rtfm.modx.com/xpdo/2.x/class-reference/xpdo/xpdo.query)?

Comment: I did. I spent a lot of time going over this and trying different things. I couldnt find a section that addresses my problem. The getCount function seems to deal with arrays, not single query results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple different methods

```
$results = $modx->query("select `username` from modx_users");

if (!is_object($results)) {
   return 'No result!';
}
else {

    $r = $results->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    echo count($r);

    print_r($r);

}





$results = $modx->query("select count(id) as uids from modx_users where id >= '1'");

if (!is_object($results)) {

   return 'No result!';
}
else {

    $r = $results->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    echo 'uids = '.$r['uids'];


}
```